# Apply changes to selected elements inside the svg element?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, dictionary, visualization

I was working on separate files to compose the map of Scotland. Then, Reading a csv file that specify the party that is the majority of the region's msps belong to. Based on the party the region would be coloured. After reading the csv file, I tried to select the regions to change their colours, but it does not work. Here is the code:

```
<script>
var dataset =[]

var width = 960,
height = 1160;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
.center([0, 55.4])
.rotate([4.4, 0])
.parallels([50, 60])
.scale(10000)
.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var gssCode = [{gss:"S12000005", reg:"central"},
{gss:"S12000014", reg:"central"},
{gss:"S12000030", reg:"central"},
{gss:"S12000006", reg:"dg"},
{gss:"S12000008", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000011", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000018", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000021", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000028", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000029", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000035", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000038", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000039", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000044", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000045", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000046", reg:"strathclyde"},
{gss:"S12000010", reg:"lothian"},
{gss:"S12000019", reg:"lothian"},
{gss:"S12000026", reg:"lothian"},
{gss:"S12000036", reg:"lothian"},
{gss:"S12000040", reg:"lothian"},
{gss:"S12000013", reg:"highland"},
{gss:"S12000017", reg:"highland"},
{gss:"S12000023", reg:"highland"},
{gss:"S12000027", reg:"highland"},
{gss:"S12000015", reg:"fife"},
{gss:"S12000020", reg:"grampian"},
{gss:"S12000033", reg:"grampian"},
{gss:"S12000034", reg:"grampian"},
{gss:"S12000024", reg:"tayside"},
{gss:"S12000041", reg:"tayside"},
{gss:"S12000042", reg:"tayside"}
];

var color = {
"Scottish Conservative and Unionist Party" : "#5ABFF4",
"Scottish Labour" : "#846DD4",
"Scottish Liberal Democrats" : "#FA6485",
"Scottish National Party" : "#F6DC60",
"Scottish Green Party" : "#31C48E",
"Independent" : "#986561",
"No Party Affiliation" : "#475070"
};

d3.csv("map_data.csv",function(error,dataset){
var region = {};
dataset.forEach(function(d){
    region[d.region]=d.party;
});

gssCode.forEach(function(d){
    d3.json(d.gss + "_topo.json", function(error, councilArea) {
        var mesh = topojson.mesh(councilArea, councilArea.objects[d.gss + "_geo"], function(a, b) {return a==b;});
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(mesh)
            .attr("class", d.reg)
            .attr("id", d.gss)
            .attr("d", path)
            .style("fill",color[region[d.reg]]);


    });


});


});
</script>
```

Comment: There is so much you could do to improve this code, it's hard to know where to start. The most fundamental observation is that you're not using data in arrays and that's where the power of D3 comes in. If you can set up an array of region IDs and names, and one of parties and colours that will make life much easier for you.

Comment: PS That's not meant as a criticism - we all have to start somewhere. If you learn how to create arrays rather than lots of variables, set up your data accordingly and then re-post your code.

Comment: @angusl I rewrote the code .. but additional problems appeared. An error in assigning mesh var.. and the itr var always printed as 32 inside the loop. when I tried to display just one region the selection part still not changing the colour of displayed area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, defining arrays instead of objects. Try this:

```
var w=960, h=1160;

var gssCode = {
    "S12000005":"central",
    "S12000014":"central",
    "S12000030":"central",
    "S12000006":"dg",
    "S12000008":"strathclyde",
    "S12000011":"strathclyde",
    "S12000018":"strathclyde",
    "S12000021":"strathclyde",
    "S12000028":"strathclyde",
    "S12000029":"strathclyde",
    "S12000035":"strathclyde",
    "S12000038":"strathclyde",
    "S12000039":"strathclyde",
    "S12000044":"strathclyde",
    "S12000045":"strathclyde",
    "S12000046":"strathclyde",
    "S12000010":"lothian",
    "S12000019":"lothian",
    "S12000026":"lothian",
    "S12000036":"lothian",
    "S12000040":"lothian",
    "S12000013":"highland",
    "S12000017":"highland",
    "S12000023":"highland",
    "S12000027":"highland",
    "S12000015":"fife",
    "S12000020":"grampian",
    "S12000033":"grampian",
    "S12000034":"grampian",
    "S12000024":"tayside",
    "S12000041":"tayside",
    "S12000042":"tayside"
};

// use your CSV here. You will need to either use queue or wrap the d3.json inside d3.csv
var pLoad = [
    {reg:"tayside",party:"Scottish Labour"},
    ...
];

var party={};
pLoad.forEach(function(d){
    party[d.reg]=d.party;
});

var color = {
    "Scottish Conservative and Unionist Party" : "#5ABFF4",
    "Scottish Labour" : "#846DD4",
    "Scottish Liberal Democrats" : "#FA6485",
    "Scottish National Party" : "#F6DC60",
    "Scottish Green Party" : "#31C48E",
    "Independent" : "#986561",
    "No Party Affiliation" : "#475070"
};

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(10000)
    .translate([w/2, h/2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",w)
    .attr("height",h);

d3.json("scotland-topojson-file.json",function(err,load){
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(load,load.objects.layer1).features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d",path)
        .style("fill",function(d){return color[party[gssCode[d.properties.gss]]];})
      .append("title")
        .text(function(d){return gssCode[d.properties.gss]+"\n"+d.properties.gss;});
});
```

Comment: I am really  sorry.. I was busy with master submissions.. the end of the semester, you know -_-" .. I used this to load the csv d3.csv("map_data.csv",function(error,d){
 
        pLoad= d.map(function(d) { return [{ "reg":d["region"] , "party":d["party"]}];});
}); but when I logged pLoad to the console.. it was empty :(

Comment: I changed the loading of csv file to fixed array of object and the coloring works.. I just could not figure out how to load csv in the format of array of objects.. I am really thankful for your time and efforts

Comment: That's Amazing! I used a tricky way to get the pLoad .. but now it is working. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Very pleased it's working for you now. I was about to take a look, so glad you're sorted now. Is this now "answered"?

Comment: yes.. I have made a vote for it.. thank you again :)

Comment: Thank you - appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer. It's not complete and almost certainly won't be error-free but it should give you the structure to work with.

One question: do you really have lots of separate files with one GSS outline in each one?  That's unusual, and it's far simpler if they're in one file.

I'd start with consolidating your array gssCode:

```
var gssCode = [
    {gss:"S12000005",reg:"central"},
    {gss:"S12000006",reg:"dg"},
    ...
];
```

We can access the GSS code using

```
gssCode[x].gss
```

and the same idea for the region.

Then I'd set up your colour lookup as an object.

```
var color = {
    "Scottish Conservative and Unionist Party": "#5ABFF4",
    "Scottish Labour": "#846DD4",
    ...
};
```

Setting this up as an object is a neat trick as you can pass the object the name of a party and get the colour back, e.g.

```
color["Scottish Labour"]="#846DD4"
```

This next section is unchanged.

```
var width = 960, height = 1160;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(10000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

This is largely your code, but I've simplified the loop that you created by using forEach, and I've loaded the CSV first, then done the JSON within that. You could use queue.js (closely related to D3) to simplify this.

```
d3.csv("map_data.csv",function(error,dataset){

    // Assuming your CSV has fields reg and party...
    var region = {};
    dataset.forEach(function(d){
        region[d.reg]=d.party;
    });
    // ... which creates an object to lookup against, region["dg"]="The majority party in DG"

    gssCode.forEach(function(d){
        d3.json(d.gss + "_topo.json", function(error, councilArea) {
            var mesh = topojson.mesh(councilArea, councilArea.objects[d.gss + "_geo"], function(a, b) {return a==b;});
            svg.append("path")
                .datum(mesh)

                // This next line is simpler because you don't need to call get_region - it's already in your gessCode array
                .attr("class", d.reg)
                .attr("id", d.gss)
                .attr("d", path)

                // This line is new, pulling in the party from your region object (the CSV) and then the colour from your color object
                .style("fill",color[region[d.reg]]);

        // Closing the d3.json
        };

    // Closing the forEach
    });

// Closing the d3.csv
});
```

I hope this helps. Use Chrome's console to spot errors, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you.. I'll try this one and come back to put whatever I end with. About the json file, I found one file that includes all the council areas of scotland, but I could not figure out how to retreive the objects that represent the areas from it. Here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bczpuu9t2uds3g/all_councils_topo.json?dl=0

Comment: I updated the code based on your answer, and now it is working as my first missy long version of the code, but still the color changing aren't applied to the map :(.. The map looks like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgmmqwzwaiumy0l/Screenshot%202014-11-25%2014.49.40.png?dl=0

Comment: If you inspect the path elements, what does it give you as the fill colour? Regarding the single file, I'll take a look later.

Comment: There is no style attribute for any of the path elements.

Comment: OK, that means that the color[region[d.reg]] isn't returning a recognised value. Move the var region={}; declaration before the d3.csv function and test it in the console. Also test the color object, and the two combined.

Comment: You could also append a title to the path to inspect values as you mouseover. Add .append("title").text(d.reg) after the .style("fill",...

Comment: It looks like that topojson file has all the councils that you need. The code you've got above can be massively simplified. To get the array of features that you need, you use .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.layer1).features)

Comment: I moved the region declaration and added these 3 lines inside gssCode.forEach: console.log(d.reg); console.log(region[d.reg]); console.log(color[region[d.reg]]); just the first one's value is printed and the region and the color objects are printed as undefined